# android equivalent of cancelBubble in DOM

Tags: android, listview, dom, gesture

In my current project I implemented a `PullToRefreshListView` with a header view, say, an `ImageView`.

A PullToRefreshListView has a header view(`RefreshView`) to show **pull to refresh** or **release to load** when you pull to list down.

However when you accidentally pull the `ImageView` (the header view), the `RefreshView` will show up because the `ImageView` is part the `PullToRefreshListView`.

```
 ___________________________                      ____________________________ 
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |                           |
|        ImageView          |                    |       ImageView           |
|                           |                    |                           |
-----------------------------                    -----------------------------
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |       RefreshView         |
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    -----------------------------
|                           |                    |                           |
|         ListView          |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |        ListView           |
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |                           |
|                           |                    |                           |
-----------------------------                    -----------------------------

          Normal                                          Pulled
```

I can find an alternative to design this but I am curious is there equivalent of `cancelBubble` (as in DOM) in Android so that I can prevent the Gesture acted on `ImageView`  from acting on the whole `PullToRefreshListView`.

**EDIT:**
The `RefreshListView` extends `ListView`. It is actually

```
public class RefreshListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener
```

I let it implement `OnScrollListener` to catch the pull-down gesture. But if I do

```
refreshListView.addHeadersView(imageView)
```

then pulling the `imageView` will cause the `RefreshView` to show up.

So I think if there is cancelBubble, the job would be easier.

Comment: What does actually trigger the `RefreshView` so far ?

Comment: @fiddler it should be triggered when you pull the `PullToRefreshListView`(except the header `ImageView`). but pulling the `ImageView` will also trigger it.

Comment: Why isn't it triggered when you only pull the `ListView` ?

Comment: I don't understand your hierarchy... Does PullToRefreshListView extend ListView or does it contain a ListView ?

Comment: well, I should edit it. thank you @fiddler

Comment: Why don't you put your header outside of the `RefreshListView`? That would solve your issue, wouldn't it ?

Comment: It is not the same. The ImageView will stay there.